# MYSQL integrating two tables in a single table without missing any row

Tags: mysql, sql, join, phpmyadmin

I have two tables representing number of users in two activities which are sorted by dates:

Table A: has DATE and NUMBER OF USERS IN ACTIVITY 1
Table B: has DATA and NUMBER OF USERS IN ACTIVITY 2

Question: how can I join them together in MYSQL (particularly I'm using PHPMYADMIN for data manipulation)? The problem I have with this piece of code is that there will be some entries missing (where there is no information about the specific day in one column):

```
SELECT a1.day, a1.count, b1.count
FROM table_A a1 
JOIN table_B b1 on a1.day = b1.day
ORDER BY a1.day
```

Comment: Could you provide some example data and desired result?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table_A

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM table_B
```

would do what you want, but if this is a regular thing, you'd be better off simply combining the two tables into a single one.

Comment: but this only shows me one column for the 'count' not the aggregation of both tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    u.day, SUM(count_A) AS count_A, SUM(count_B) AS count_B
FROM
(SELECT day, count AS count_A, 0 AS count_B
FROM table_A
UNION ALL
SELECT day, 0, count 
FROM table_B) AS u
GROUP BY u.day
ORDER BY u.day
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a `FULL OUTER JOIN` of your two tables, which can be simulated in MySQL like so:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     (
         SELECT     a.day, a.count, b.count
         FROM       table_A a
         LEFT JOIN  table_B b ON a.day = b.day

         UNION ALL

         SELECT     a.day, a.count, b.count
         FROM       table_A a
         RIGHT JOIN table_B b ON a.day = b.day
         WHERE      a.day IS NULL
         ) a
ORDER BY a.day
```

Comment: This works too @Zane. Thanks for the clarification on combination of UNION and JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're attempting to combine two tables and add the values of the 'count' field, grouped by 'day' (what will likely be 'user').

There are several methods of accomplishing what I think you're attempting to do. In this method, we'll CREATE a table and INSERT the values of Table_A and Table_B using a UNION ALL, SUM, and GROUP BY.

```
create table `Table_C` (
   `id` int unsigned primary key auto_increment,
   `day` varchar(16),
   `count` integer
);

INSERT INTO `Table_C`
SELECT * FROM ( 
    SELECT
         0 AS `id`,
        `day`,
        SUM(`count`)
    FROM ( 
       SELECT `a`.`day` AS `day`, `a`.`count` AS `count` FROM `Table_A` `a` 
         UNION ALL
       SELECT `b`.`day` AS `day`, `b`.`count` AS `count` FROM `Table_B` `b`
         ) AS `u` 
    GROUP BY `u`.`day`
    ORDER BY `u`.`day`
) AS `t1`;
```

However, there 'user' of the activity is not accounted for here.